# Developing spotify audio plugins in c++ with Juce

Tags: c++, spotify

Is this possible at all ?

I would like to use Juce to create spotify free and opensource audio plugins (EQ, limiter and stuff like that).

If I my understanding is correct, you can use libspotify to develop your own client, or you can use spotify API to interact with spotify's own client, but only in Javascript.

Is there any way (preferably cross platform), to develop a c++ plugin for the official spotify  client ?

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no — Spotify doesn't provide a native plugin API like that. However, you could properly apply filters to the audio after it's left Spotify — i.e., at the system level.

Comment: So, that implies coding a "virtual" device driver right ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, after some more research, there is a way but it's a bit of a hack and it's not cross-platform. You can create a proxy library for Direct Sound, which does the sound processing then forwards the audio to the real direct sound library.